Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular' in '\UX\node_modules@uirouter\angularjs\lib-esm'
Since Angular 1.8.3 now has a vulnerability, we attempted to remove it from our project's package.json. However, due to a dependency on AngularJS in uirouter/angular-hybrid, removing AngularJS caused an error during the build process. To address this, we replaced uirouter/angular-hybrid with uirouter/angular and updated the related imports from UIRouterUpgradeModule to UIRouterModule from the uirouter/angular package. Our codebase was migrated to Angular 8 some time ago, but given its size, we are uncertain if there are any remaining references to AngularJS. Does this approach seem correct? If not, what alternative steps should we consider?
ERROR in ./node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/lib-esm/angular.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular' in '\UX\node_modules@uirouter\angularjs\lib-esm'
@ ./node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/lib-esm/angular.js 2:0-42 4:31-45 4:49-70 4:73-87
@ ./node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/lib-esm/services.js
@ ./node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/lib-esm/index.js
@ ./node_modules/@uirouter/angular-hybrid/lib/angular-hybrid.js
@ ./node_modules/@uirouter/angular-hybrid/lib/index.js

